# 3 Monitor display on a AMD A8-6600k

Tags: graphics-card, multiple-monitors, hdmi, vga, dvi

I have an AMD A8-6600k. I can extend my display using VGA and HDMI. Vga to my widescreen lcd, and HDMI to my TV. I am a programmer and I needed to test resolutions from the TV, and monitor. One of my clients is using a Square monitor like the CRT ones. I have an old flatscreen monitor here with VGA input. Can I extend display on 3 of my monitors. I dont want the hassle of switching them back whenever I test a different resolution.

My setup now:

VGA to VGA (Wide LCD)
HDMI to HDMI(Big LCD TV)
*DVI-D to VGA (Standard LCD)

*= I have a DVI-I to VGA Converter connector but the problem is this one cannot fit to my DVI slot, because it is DVI-D. I removed the 4+1 pins to fit it (I read it somewhere where this could be done). I still cannot see a 3rd monitor from the Screen Resolution list. Before I buy another "proper" converter. Is this setup possible?

[image: My CPU's back]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

there is no way to get a 3 monitor display with vga included. i had the same problem with my fathers computer but luckily his mobo also had a display port. your only chance it to get an after market graphics card to either crossfire with or use aside from your apu. if you do decide to use an aftermarket card without crossfiring you will experience a slight cpu boost to 4.1 Mhz. all of these statements are from personal experience.

Comment: yes, I already did just that to make a 3rd monitor work. thank you